# Array cleaning in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

I have an array in Swift:

```
["\"100003866283798-2\"", "\"100001986741004-2\"",     
"\"100003455181526-2\"", "\"100002261472542-2\"", 
"\"100003866283798-3\"", "\"100003866283798-0\"",
"\"100001986741004-3\"", "\"100001986741004-0\"", 
"\"100003455181526-3\"", "\"100003455181526-0\"", 
"\"100002261472542-3\"", "\"100002261472542-0\""]
```

and I only want the numbers, not the quotes and the `-2`.

I can't figure out to do this, because when I type

```
let cleanStr = numberArray.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil)
```

it gives the error:

> Value of type '[String]' has no member
>   'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString'

I know it's very confusing with all the quotes etc but I want these numbers without their quotes etc, anyone a solution?

Comment: You need to `map` the array and remove the junk one by one from each string. Also, I'd suggest using a regex for the purpose, perhaps `/([0-9]+[^-])/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let newArray = array.map { (string: String) -> String in
    let woFirst = string.characters.dropFirst()
    let tilDash = woFirst.prefixUpTo(
        woFirst.indexOf("-") ?? woFirst.endIndex)
    return String(tilDash)
}
```

(Weirdly it doesn't compile without the type annotation). Or if you feel fancy:

```
let newArray = array
    .map{ {$0.prefixUpTo($0.indexOf("-") ?? $0.endIndex)}($0.characters.dropFirst()) }
    .map(String.init)
```

(XCode 7 beta 6)

Comment: thanks! Right now there are still one pair of quotes around each number, and the -0 should disappear, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @ᗹᖆᕠᗰᖇᓏᕦᒹᗗᘗᖱᖶᔚ With the array you posted in your question, my answer works, if you have a different array of Strings you should post that one instead

Comment: Oh yeah yeah it works indeed, I forgot to load it into my table view, my excuses!

Answer (score 0):

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString
```

works only with `NSString` not `Array`. Then you must iterate your array remove excess char.

Comment: what do you mean by iterate?

Comment: I mean : for element: NSString  in array{ // do stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString here for element}

Comment: for var clean:NSString in numberArray {
            
            clean.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
        }